# Python Networkx: Visualize an edge weight with a bubble/circle

Tags: python, graph, networkx, weighted

I am trying to plot a network in python using networkx.
on the edges there should be circle or bubbles with sizes according to the weight of the edges.
Lets say I have
the nodes
A, B, C, D

the edges an their weigths (w):

```
A->B, w=1
A->C, w=1
A->D, w=2
B->C, w=3
B->D, w=2
C->D, w=4
```

and this is what I want to have:
[click for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yah3Z.png)

Is there any possiility to do that? Or do you have any suggestion?

This is my code by now, but i was only able to change the edge width, but not to put circles/bubbles on the edge:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('A', pos=(0,5))
G.add_node('B', pos=(3,12))
G.add_node('C', pos=(3,6))
G.add_node('D', pos=(7,-4))
weights = [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
G.add_edge('A', 'B', weight=weights[0])
G.add_edge('A', 'C', weight=weights[1])
G.add_edge('A', 'D', weight=weights[2])
G.add_edge('B', 'C', weight=weights[3])
G.add_edge('B', 'D', weight=weights[4])
G.add_edge('C', 'D', weight=weights[5])
pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')

labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=weights)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels)

plt.show()
```

Thanks a lot
Uli

Comment: Probably adding another set of nodes to represent the desired "bubbles"=edge weights. Then you can control the size of these nodes via the node size argument (and node color).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the library created by Paul Brodersen.

[Link to GitHub](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph/blob/master/netgraph/_main.py)

He wrote a library that is kind of an extension of the Nx Graph library. You can update your dictionary (or create a new one) that contains the color and the size of the nodes.

```
node_size = {}
node_color = {}
# Some Arguments to fill the dict (with scalars and Matplotlib colors)
```

And finally plot the data:

```
Graph(G, node_size=node_size, node_color=node_color)
```

Preferable you have all your data in dictionaries.